# How I can achive a google map showing only landscape borders?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to styling google map. I want only border of landscape. So water and landscape will be the same colour but highlighting landscape only border with a different colour.
What I have currently is

```
{
    featureType: 'landscape',
    elementType: 'geometry',
    stylers: [{ color: '#012B4D' }]
},
{
    featureType: 'water',
    elementType: 'all',
    stylers: [{ color: '#021E35' }]
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the landscape geometries' stroke color (see the [style reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference)). Right now you're setting both the fill (interior) and stroke (border) to the same color. You can access these by using `geometry.fill` and `geometry.stroke` for `elementType`. If you wanted to set the landscape borders to white and the landscape and water fill to the same color, your code might look something like this:

```
{
   featureType: 'landscape',
   elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
   stylers: [{ color: '#FFFFFF' }]
},
{
   featureType: 'landscape',
   elementType: 'geometry.fill',
   stylers: [{ color: '#012B4D' }]
},
{
   featureType: 'water',
   elementType: 'all',
   stylers: [{ color: '#012B4D' }]
},
```

Comment: I tried here. console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/studio/styles/new;experience=style-editor?project=your-project. that does not help.